# Write conflict; Need an event that triggers with popup form activation in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have frmMain that has a number of subforms that are contained in several tabs on tab control on frmMain.  I have subForm3 on one of the tabs of frmMain.  subForm3 has a textbox control called tbxNote.  tbxNote requires one user to make changes to the note based on feedback from a supervisor that is shown in a separate, non-modal popup form called frmFloater that appears above frmMain so that the supervisor's note shown in the non-modal form can be seen while tbxNote in frmMain.subForm3 is being editted.

Now, both frmMain and frmFloater can change the data in the same table.  I understand that this is what is causing the write conflict error I am receiving.

So, I want to be able to trigger a save of the data in subForm3 when the user exits tbxNote, for example, the user exits by clicking frmFloater or a control in frmFloater.  And, I want to trigger a save of the data in frmFloater when I exit frmFloater or click a control in frmMain.

The problem I am running into is that I cannot find an event that triggers when I leave frmMain or when I enter frmFloater; nor can I find an event when I leave frmFloater or when I enter frmMain.

I have tried the following events for frmMain (and also in frmFloater), none of which trigger when the user leaves frmMain (e.g., by clicking into frmFloater) nor do they trigger when the user leaves frmFloater (e.g., by clicking into frmMain):

1. On Deactivate
2. On Activate
3. On Current
4. On Click
5. On Got Focus
6. On Lost Focus

How can I detect switching to a different form so that I can save out the data in the first form before handing control over to the 2nd form?

Comment: Note: I just discovered in a MS Support document ([link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm3)) that the Deactivate event does not occur when the user switches to a form that has the PopUp property set to Yes.  However, that is exactly the event that I need to trap, or, I need a way to display frmFloating on top of frmMain without frmFloating having the PopUp property set to Yes--that could solve the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 forms showing 1 record, you will always run into problems. I would look at separating the record into 2 tables and creating a relationship between the tables to prevent corruptions of records. For example:

Table 1 will hold the main information of the record being viewed
Table 2 will hold the supervisor notes

The relationship between the tables will be either a 1 to 1 (if you want a note to be a single record and all updates the current note) or a 1 to many (if you want multiple records with multiple notes

be sure to check "enforce referential integrity", "Cascade Updating", and "Cascade Deleting". Otherwise you will have orphan records.

To answer your question, it cannot be done with the current setup. If employee A is editing the record on frmMain and a supervisor opens frmFloater and begins adding notes. You just corrupted the record... Reason being is, you cannot have the front end the employee has save the record the front end the supervisor has. only their machine can save the record the specific person has accessed. make sense?

There is another solution, and that would be making frmFloater an unbound form. There is quite a bit of programming involved to accomplish this, but once I made all my forms in my Access Databases unbound and all the controls unbound, I never had a corrupted record incident again. But this requires a button building the query before opening the form, open the form, then take the values from the query and place the values in the corresponding textbox on your form, then close the query. This will give you a snapshot view of the record on the table without being bound to it. Your button/afterupdate event can then run an update query on the record without locking it.

Let me know if this helped or if this did not make sense. If it didn't make sense, I'll try to explain a little better.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for a detailed response. To clarify: there are not 2 different users--it is one user who can modify the same record from 2 different forms showing simultaneously. Yes, the idea of 2 different Tables could work with lots of coding. Switching to unbound forms means whichever of the 2 forms does the update to the "real" record first will get overwritten when the second form does its unbound update of the "real" record. The problem for which I was really hoping to find an answer was how to catch the event related to changing from a Form to a Popup Form, but it appears not possible.